# Function calls that don't do anything in C++

Tags: c++, return-value

Why when I call the `factorial` function it doesn't do anything?

Is this the right way to implement a factorial function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
       return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
 }

 int main()
 {
     int x = 3;
     cout << x << endl;
     factorial(x);
     cout << x;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should not pass anything by reference here.

Comment: Research Factorial tables.  Factorials grow very fast.   While factorial(20) 'fits' in a uint64_t,  factorial(21) will cause wrap-around.  If int on your machine / os  is smaller than uint64_t, overflow will happen sooner.  Your code looks ok.

Comment: I like recursion.  Your's is ok.  For your test and eval, I suggest you also implement a iterative factorial using a for-loop (to feel more confident about your recursion results).  There is also an analytical factorial (which is O(1) but very slow).  (The fastest approach is table lookup)

Comment: If you should want the factorial of a number > 20, then I recommend The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (of https://gmplib.org), specifically mpz_class (for integers).  Using mpz_class, it is 'trivial' to compute factorial(1000) and cout (for no good reason) the thousands of chars thus generated.

Answer (score 9):

The result of `factorial` is discarded, i.e., not bound to a variable to be processed further. The fix is simple:

```
const int result = factorial(x);

cout << "The result is " << result << "\n";
```

This is a nice demonstration when the C++17 [nodiscard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute can be helpful. If the function signature reads

```
[[nodiscard]] int factorial(int n)
```

compilers will complain when the return value is not bound to a variable, e.g.

```
factorial(42); // warning: ignoring return value of 'int factorial(int)', declared with attribute nodiscard [-Wunused-result]
```

Comment: I was going to comment about the last bit, which is a bit of a lie one tells to little children, but then decided it's a good lie to tell. +1

Comment: @StoryTeller What do you mean?

Comment: @Quentin - `+factorial(42);`

Comment: @StoryTeller "warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value] +factorial(x);"

Comment: @Caleth - Remove `-Wall` (and let's not discuss how good an idea it is). GCC still warns due to the attribute unless `+` is added.

Comment: @StoryTeller *shudder*

Comment: @StoryTeller I think I'm just being dense, but I still don't get it. Do people run around prefixing stuff with `+`, and thus the attribute is useless?

Comment: @Quentin - Well no, I was more aiming at "it must be placed in a variable". It doesn't, it just has to be used. But putting it in a variable is still good advice, so I set out to confuse people.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ooh, alright, yeah. Well that was very effective :p

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `factorial` function to both pass by reference **and** use a return value for the recursive calculation, circumventing your reference multiplication error like so:

```
 int factorial(int &n){
   if (n <= 1){
      return n = 1;
   }
   else {
     int c = n - 1;
     return n = n * factorial(c);
   }

 }
```

I don't really like this method though, since it would be much simpler to just print the return value of  the function instead of going lengths to make it pass a reference.